# checkboxes, if checked need to sums its price in divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a page [(here you can see it)](https://www.tecmasolutions.com/clients/home-configurator-1/checkout.php?tipo=B_7.1&stile=classic&allestimento=silver&pavimento=Listone%20Giordano%20-%20Linea%2070)
in which if i click on a checkbox I need to sum its price to actual price.

The checkboxes have a `value` and a `data-prezzo`. those two numbers need to sums to two different divs like that:

`value` + `rata-display-1` = `total_rata`

`data-prezzo` + `prezzo-somma` = `total_prezzo`

I'm new so i don't know why it gave me NaN instead the correct sum.

here's the code:

```js
//sommo rata e prezzo dei plus a quelli del DB
var basicPrice_rata = 1000 ; // This is how we start
var basicPrice_prezzo = 50000 ; // This is how we start
    
$(document).on('change', getCheck);
    function getCheck() {
    var currentPrice_rata = basicPrice_rata; // every time
    CurrentPrice_rata = basicPrice_rata;
    var currentPrice_prezzo = basicPrice_prezzo; // every time
    CurrentPrice_prezzo = basicPrice_prezzo;
        plus = [],
        total_rata = 1000;
        total_prezzo = 50000; 

    $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(i, el) {

        if ($(el).is(":checked")) {
            total_rata += parseInt($(el).val());
            total_prezzo += parseInt($(el).data('prezzo'));

            console.log(total_rata);
            plus.push($(el).data('name')); // get the label text
            }
    });


//inserisco i nomi dei plus nella riga di testo
 $("#plus-display").text(plus.join(", "));
    
//inserisco le rate sommate  nei div corrispondenti
 $('#rata-display-2').text(total_rata +" €");
    
//inserisco i prezzi sommati  nei div corrispondenti
 $('#prezzo-somma').text(total_prezzo +" €");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="134.24" data-prezzo="40000" id="box-auto" name="Box auto" data-name="Box auto" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input">
<input type="checkbox" value="17.78" data-prezzo="5000" id="posto-moto" name="Posto moto" data-name="Posto moto" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input">
<input type="checkbox" value="134.24" data-prezzo="40000" id="box-auto" name="Box auto" data-name="Box auto" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input">

<div id="rata-display-2" class="prezzo-checkout">1000 €</div>

<div id="prezzo-somma" class="text-checkout color bold">500000 €</div>

<div id="plus-display" class="text_piccolo black checkout">Interior Pack Incluso nel prezzo</div>
```

Comment: Use `$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')` to get rid of the `if ($(el).is(":checked"))`

Comment: Your snippet doesn't run, but having done a quick inspect of your actual website, the problem only appears when you click the top checkbox - and the problem (well, at least part of it) is that this checkbox doesn't have a `data-prezzo` attribute, which your script needs to be able to parse into an integer.

Comment: Not does it have a `value` attribute, and this is the cause of the second `NaN`

Comment: Hi @RobinZigmond ok i've solved the problem but now i have a different problem, when i sum the price (the base price is 500.000, and I want to sum 20.000) it change the total to 520 and not 520.000.
and when i sum the othet price (1000 + 17,78) the price is licke 27.780 
i think i need to format the number but I don't know how. Can you help me?

Comment: @StefanoZanetti if you have a different problem then ask a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your code is working as expected which is only missing the functions's closing `}`

```js
//sommo rata e prezzo dei plus a quelli del DB
var basicPrice_rata = 1000 ; // This is how we start
var basicPrice_prezzo = 50000 ; // This is how we start
    
$(document).on('change', getCheck);
    function getCheck() {
    var currentPrice_rata = basicPrice_rata; // every time
    CurrentPrice_rata = basicPrice_rata;
    var currentPrice_prezzo = basicPrice_prezzo; // every time
    CurrentPrice_prezzo = basicPrice_prezzo;
        plus = [],
        total_rata = 1000;
        total_prezzo = 50000; 

    $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(i, el) {

        if ($(el).is(":checked")) {
            total_rata += parseInt($(el).val());
            total_prezzo += parseInt($(el).data('prezzo'));

            //console.log(total_rata);
            plus.push($(el).data('name')); // get the label text
            }
    });


//inserisco i nomi dei plus nella riga di testo
 $("#plus-display").text(plus.join(", "));
    
//inserisco le rate sommate  nei div corrispondenti
 $('#rata-display-2').text(total_rata +" €");
    
//inserisco i prezzi sommati  nei div corrispondenti
 $('#prezzo-somma').text(total_prezzo +" €");
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="134.24" data-prezzo="40000" id="box-auto" name="Box auto" data-name="Box auto" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input">
<input type="checkbox" value="17.78" data-prezzo="5000" id="posto-moto" name="Posto moto" data-name="Posto moto" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input">
<input type="checkbox" value="134.24" data-prezzo="40000" id="box-auto" name="Box auto" data-name="Box auto" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input">

<div id="rata-display-2" class="prezzo-checkout">1000 €</div>

<div id="prezzo-somma" class="text-checkout color bold">500000 €</div>

<div id="plus-display" class="text_piccolo black checkout">Interior Pack Incluso nel prezzo</div>
```

Comment: ok i've solved the problem but now i have a different problem, when i sum the price (the base price is 500.000, and I want to sum 20.000) it change the total to 520 and not 520.000.
and when i sum the othet price (1000 + 17,78) the price is licke 27.780 
i think i need to format the number but I don't know how. Can you help me?

Comment: @StefanoZanetti, in that case simply use `.toFixed()` like `total_rata.toFixed(3)`.....thanks.